# npm update failed in docker

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, npm, npm-update

I can't update npm package xxx in **docker** by

```
npm update -g
```

or

```
npm install -g xxx
```

After update, I can't execute xxx, and throw

```
Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
```

So I have to

```
npm uninstall -g xxx 
npm install -g xxx
```

to reinstall every time I want to update package.
How can I update npm package in docker?

Comment: In which environment you're facing this issue windows (or) linux?

Comment: @DavidR  Debian8 64bit

Comment: Guess, you need to  completely remove your `node_modules`, directory using the `rm` command and do a complete uninstall like how you tried earlier.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `npm rm` command to remove your `node_modules` directory.

Comment: Will I do this every time I want to update my npm package? If it is, it didn't solve the problem at all.

Comment: Did it work when you tried it?

Comment: I had remove all node and npm (include node_modules, of course) and reinstall them in docker and commited docker. And after some time, the error occurred when I updated npm package which is outdated.

Answer (score -1):

> How can I update npm package in docker?

you re-build your image and re-deploy it with the update built into the image.

a docker container isn't a virtual machine - it's not something should be required to live forever. a docker container should be easily destroyed and re-created.

when you need an update to your code / libraries, you should rebuild the image with the updates in the image, and then deploy the new image, stopping the old container and starting a new one based on the new image.

Comment: I get the error "can not find module xxx " before I exit my temporary docker container.If I commit or export the container the problem must still exists.

Comment: Except if you want to iterate very quickly, one method is to mount your code in a container (e.g. based on node:latest), run bash, so you can code-test extremely quickly.  With npm5 that is now broken (getting the same problem plus other issues, go visit the npm issues page...)